# How to correct wrong data type in Excel raw data file when reading it in to Pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've imported data from multiple Excel files and some of the values are formatted incorrectly in the raw data files. For example, when I import the data, my table looks like this:

```
        Date                 Income
2010-01:05 00:00:00           3500
      Unknown                Unknown   
2010-02:10 00:00:00           5400
       44566          1912-04-26 00:00:00
```

As you can see, the last row has wrong data types. The data in each row was imported from each Excel file in the directory. One row represents one single Excel file. I checked the raw Excel data file of the last row, and the date column is formatted as "Number". Plus, the income column is formatted as "Date" and appears as "4/26" when it should be 4500. "Unknown" is also a valid value.

I'm extracting the data from 1000+ raw data files and have many cases where the values have wrong data format. I can't manually correct the data types in each Excel file.

I tired to specify the data type when I read in the files like this but it is not working because I can import them only as 'str' because of 'Unknown'. For example, I can't do something like this because it raises an error because of the "Unknown"s and I want to keep them as they are valid data as well.

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + 'filename.xlsx', header=0, converters={'Date': datetime, 'Income':float})
```

So I tried to convert 45566 to datetime (2022-01-05 00:00:00) and 1912-04-26 00:00:00 to number (4500) but it's not working.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

If I run the code above, it does convert 45566 to datetime but the date is incorrect. For example, it says "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000044566" instead of "2022-01-05 00:00:00"

```
df['Income'] = df['Income'].astype('float')
```

I ran this code after excluding the rows with "Unknown" but it still raise an error saying "could not convert string to float: '1912-04-26 00:00:00'

How do I resolve this issue to get the correct data types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the dates use:

```
from datetime import datetime
import xlrd
date=42988
print(xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0).date())
```